# Why are there two html nodes in a single-node html document?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to use DOMdocument to retrieve a list of html nodes for doing a [CSS3 tree html visualization](http://francisco.io/tree) (disclaimer: my own page). However, I have a problem with the following code, the minimum one that reproduces the error:

```
// Compressed, testing html
$text = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Demo</title></head><body>Bla</body></html>';

// Create and load the html
$dom = new DOMdocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);

// Error test: it prints two html nodes instead of one
foreach ($dom->childNodes as $node)
  echo $node->nodeName;
```

The expected result is `html`, since I'm working with an html document and that's the top node. However, I'm obtaining `htmlhtml`, and the first node is empty (another check) while the second one holds all the valuable info. So,

> **Why are there two `html` nodes in a single-node html document?**

Note: I've tried deleting the `<!DOCTYPE html>` and the `<html>` tags but neither *solution* worked.

If you are not able to answer the previous question for any reason, at least answer this: will there always be two `html` nodes and the second one contain all the valuable information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the 1st node is a DOCUMENT_TYPE (type = 10), which seems to be always created, even with no `<!DOCTYPE>`.
I suppose DOMdocument needs it to process the rest of the document.

The second node is your "real" document.

You can see the contents quickly like so:

```
$text = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Demo</title><script>var a=10;</script></head><body>Bla</body></html>';

$dom = new DOMdocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);

foreach ($dom->childNodes as $node)
{
    echo $node->nodeName;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($node);echo"</pre><br>\n";
    echo "<pre>";print_r(getArray($node));echo"</pre><br>";
    echo "<br>================================<br>";
}

function getArray($node)
{
    $array = false;

    if ($node->hasAttributes())
    {
        foreach ($node->attributes as $attr)
        {
            $array[$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
        }
    }

    if ($node->hasChildNodes())
    {
        if ($node->childNodes->length == 1)
        {
            $array[$node->firstChild->nodeName] = $node->firstChild->nodeValue;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode)
            {
                if ($childNode->nodeType != XML_TEXT_NODE)
                {
                    $array[$childNode->nodeName][] = getArray($childNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If no doctype is present in loadHTML($input), the latter wraps the
$input with it's own doctype, moreover, as you've mentioned yourself, removing all
html tags yelds the same tesult.

If you run this code:

```
$text = '<head><title>Demo</title></head><body>Bla</body>';


$dom = new DOMdocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The output will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><title>Demo</title></head><body>Bla</body></html>
```

The answer is yes, there will be always two parent html tags, where the second one holds the dom structure;

PS: loadHTML will enclose non-closed tags automatically also. See [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php)